# How do you fetch data? By page or by component?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, graphql, frontend

Let's say I have a page - dashboard and 3 components on it: My notes, my friends posts and my notifications. Now how would you approach fetching data for that page? Would you rather do something like this:

```
query Dashboard{
  getMyNotes{...}
  getMyFriends{...}
  getMyNotifications{...}
}
```

or would you make 3 separate queries inside those components? Second approach seems to be slower because you need to make 3 requests to the server but also it seems less messy frontend wise because you don't need to pass props to those components which makes it easier to use them across whole application. Or maybe it doesn't matter all that much? What do you think?

Comment: depends on ... f.e. update requirements ... data fetched in one request can be used without passing as prop ... apollo client (with normalizing cache), cache-only or cache-first policy

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple i would do 3 requests. And it will probably not be slower at all. Maybe even faster since these requests will run simultaneously.

Comment: Well that sounds alright. I've totally missed that requests will run simultaneously